# how to access an array within an object

Tags: java, arrays, object

Write a fully-documented class named Menu which stores a list of items in an array and provides an interface to interact with this list. A Menu can hold up to 50 items at a time, so use the final variable MAX_ITEMS = 50.

I created the constructor and a separate class called MenuItem

```
    public class Menu implements Cloneable {

        final int MAX_ITEMS = 50;

        public Menu(){
            MenuItem[] menu =  new MenuItem[MAX_ITEMS];
        }
    }
```

I want to create a method that clones a Menu. How do I access the properties of each individual MenuItem within Menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating `MenuItem[] menu` as a local variable and never storing it after the constructor. So not only can you not clone it, you can't ever access it again.

Try using a field for the `menu` variable, like this:

```
public class Menu implements Cloneable {

    final int MAX_ITEMS = 50;
    private MenuItem[] menu;

    public Menu(){
        menu =  new MenuItem[MAX_ITEMS];
    }
}
```

Now any method within the Menu class can access the `menu` you set during construction.

As for cloning, it depends how deeply you want to clone. If you just want a new Menu object that refers to the same `menu` array in memory, see cloneOne. If you want a new Menu object with a new `menu` array containing the same objects as the old `menu` array, see cloneTwo. If you want to go further than that, you'll have to put up some details for the MenuItem class:

```
public class Menu implements Cloneable {

    final int MAX_ITEMS = 50;
    private MenuItem[] menu;

    public Menu(){
        menu =  new MenuItem[MAX_ITEMS];
    }

    public Menu cloneOne(){
        Menu a = new Menu();
        a.menu = menu;
        return a;
    }

    public Menu cloneTwo(){
        Menu a = new Menu();
        a.menu = new MenuItem[menu.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
            a.menu[i] = menu[i];
        return a;
}
```

Comment: if I use cloneTwo will I be able to change one without it changing the other too?

Comment: Yep, cloneTwo will allow that behavior. However, if you make an alteration to a menuItem that happens to be in both Menu objects, it will be altered in both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to go through all that, assuming A is the menu...

```
public static Menu clone(){
Menu B = this;
return B;
}
```

Then simply call it using

```
Menu B = A.clone();
```

Comment: The default clone method will not do a deep copy, which means that they will share menu items.